# After saving the value as a string in the datastore preference, resetting the preference when the app is reloaded

Tags: android

This is My Code

```
class UserTextFieldPreferencesRepository(private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>) {
        
        private companion object {
        val USER_INPUT_TEXT = stringPreferencesKey("user_input_text")
        const val TAG = "TextFiledPreferencesRepo"
    }
    // Store values ​​in dataStore
    suspend fun saveTextPreference(inputText: String) {
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[USER_INPUT_TEXT] = inputText
        }
    }

    // Get value from dataStore
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    var inputText: Flow<String> = dataStore.data
        .catch {
            if (it is IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error reading preferences.", it)
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw it
            }
        }
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[USER_INPUT_TEXT] ?: ""
        }
}
```

```
class FlightSearchViewModel(
    private val userTextFieldPreferencesRepository: UserTextFieldPreferencesRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val uiState: StateFlow<String> =
        userTextFieldPreferencesRepository.inputText.map {
            it
        }.stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
            initialValue = ""
        )

    fun inputText(inputText: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userTextFieldPreferencesRepository.saveTextPreference(inputText = inputText)
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun FlightSearchApp(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: FlightSearchViewModel = viewModel(factory = FlightSearchViewModel.factory)
) {
    val userInputText = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState().value
    var textFieldValues: String by remember { mutableStateOf(userInputText) }
    viewModel.inputText(textFieldValues)

        TextField(
            value = textFieldValues,
            onValueChange = { textFieldValues = it },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
         )
}
```

When a value is entered in the Textfield, the value is saved to the Datastore. I confirmed that the value of val userInputText is changing through Log.d while changing the value of Textfield.
But when I run the app again,

```
stateIn(
           scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted. WhileSubscribed(5_000),
            initialValue=""
        )
```

It is initialized with the initialValue value in .
How can I get the value from datastore instead of initialValue when the app is re-run?